# Ng-Click update the service factory value to reflect in other controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make an ng-click change the value in my factory and for the other controllers in my application to reflect that change.

Factory:

```
app.factory('data', function() {
  function changeMe(inc) {
      return 1;
  }
  return {
        changeMe: changeMe
    };
});
```

Controllers:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.change = data.changeMe();

  // I want this to change data.changeMe so that the secCtrl will reflect
  // the change as well.
  $scope.addOne = function(){
    $scope.change = data.changeMe() + 1;
  }
});

app.controller('secCtrl', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.change = data.changeMe();
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-click=addOne()>{{change}}!</p>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="secCtrl">
    <p>{{change}}
  </div>
```

How can I make it so that the ng-click changes the value in the secCtrl as well. I want them both to get updated in the Html.

A plunkr of the above:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4LsWMzwapgYpcz3hzI72?p=preview

Comment: Your controllers will either need to `$watch` the value (which will take some reconstructing of your factory), or use event broadcasting/emitting to inform other controllers something changed

Comment: Here's an example using `$scope.$watch`: http://jsfiddle.net/ZeJQ9/ - I don't usually like using `$watch` a lot, but it gets the job done here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the addOne function into your data factory, and also store the change variable in there as well. I've forked your plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/un4sH1nI4JP5Gd1Ze26D?p=preview

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Factory

```
app.factory('data', function() {
  return {
        changeMe: function(i) {
           this.currentValue = i;
        },
        currentValue: 0
    };
});
```

Controllers

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, data) {
    $scope.change = data.currentValue;

    // I want this to change data.changeMe so that the secCtrl will reflect
    // the change as well.
    $scope.addOne = function(){
      data.changeMe(1);
    }
});

app.controller('secCtrl', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.change = data.currentValue;
})
```